Meaning of Achamanam?
Achamanam ritual which is done before worship has any esoteric meaning ?
Or it has to something with body(astral or causal) or mind ?
Like mantra chanted by sidda will give immediate effect but for others it won't, is it same for aachmanam ?
References:

Which scripture is the source for this Achamanam?

What scripture does the original Achamanam mantra come from?


